# File format or file extension is not valid

Tags: excel, vba

Until recently I've been using Excel 2013 but I've now upgraded to office 365. The Excel file i'm referring to was built in 2013. I have a macro that will save the 'Report' tab and attach this to an email however the attachment returns the below error when attempting to open;

'Excel cannot open the file 'Document1.xlsm' because the file format or file extension is not valid. Verify that the file has not been corrupted and that the file extension matches the format of the file'

I've checked that both the original Excel file and attachment are the same file format. Below is the VBA - Any suggestions on what to try would be greatly appreciated :)

```
Sub EmailSelectedSheets()

Dim SourceWB As Workbook
Dim DestinWB As Workbook
Dim OutlookApp As Object
Dim OutlookMessage As Object
Dim TempFileName As Variant
Dim ExternalLinks As Variant
Dim TempFilePath As String
Dim FileExtStr As String
Dim DefaultName As String
Dim UserAnswer As Long
Dim x As Long

Dim Rng As Range, mystr As String

'Optimize Code
  Application.ScreenUpdating = False
  Application.EnableEvents = False
  Application.DisplayAlerts = False

'Copy only selected sheets into new workbook
  Set SourceWB = ActiveWorkbook
  Sheet5.Select
  SourceWB.Windows(1).SelectedSheets.Copy
  Set DestinWB = ActiveWorkbook


'Determine Temporary File Path
  TempFilePath = Environ$("temp") & "\"

'Determine Default File Name for InputBox

    TempFileName = "Test"
  If SourceWB.Saved Then
    DefaultName = Left(SourceWB.Name, InStrRev(SourceWB.Name, ".") - 1)
  Else
    DefaultName = SourceWB.Name
  End If

  
'Determine File Extension
  If SourceWB.Saved = True Then
    FileExtStr = "." & LCase(Right(SourceWB.Name, Len(SourceWB.Name) - InStrRev(SourceWB.Name, ".", , 1)))
  Else
    FileExtStr = ".xlsm"
  End If

'Break External Links
  ExternalLinks = DestinWB.LinkSources(Type:=xlLinkTypeExcelLinks)

    'Loop Through each External Link in ActiveWorkbook and Break it
      On Error Resume Next
        For x = 1 To UBound(ExternalLinks)
          DestinWB.BreakLink Name:=ExternalLinks(x), Type:=xlLinkTypeExcelLinks
        Next x
      On Error GoTo 0
      
'Save Temporary Workbook
  DestinWB.SaveCopyAs TempFilePath & TempFileName & FileExtStr

'Create Instance of Outlook
  On Error Resume Next
    Set OutlookApp = GetObject(Class:="Outlook.Application") 'Handles if Outlook is already open
  Err.Clear
    If OutlookApp Is Nothing Then Set OutlookApp = CreateObject(Class:="Outlook.Application") 'If not, open Outlook
    
    If Err.Number = 429 Then
      MsgBox "Outlook could not be found, aborting.", 16, "Outlook Not Found"
      GoTo ExitSub
    End If
  On Error GoTo 0

'Create a new email message
  Set OutlookMessage = OutlookApp.CreateItem(0)

'Create Outlook email with attachment

  On Error Resume Next
  
    Set Rng = Worksheets("Sheet4").Range("B7:B23")
    Set Rng = Worksheets("Sheet4").Range("B7:B23").Merge(True)
    mystr = Join(Application.Transpose(Rng.Value), ";")
  
    With OutlookMessage
     .SentOnBehalfOfName "management@test.com"
     .To = Sheet4.Range("B6").Text
     .CC = ""
     .BCC = ""
     .Subject = TempFileName
     .Body = "Please find attached the latest report." & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "Kind regards"
     .Attachments.Add TempFilePath & TempFileName & FileExtStr
     .Display
    End With
  On Error GoTo 0

'Close & Delete the temporary file
  DestinWB.Close SaveChanges:=False
  Kill TempFilePath & TempFileName & FileExtStr

'Clear Memory
  Set OutlookMessage = Nothing
  Set OutlookApp = Nothing
  
'Optimize Code
ExitSub:
  Application.ScreenUpdating = True
  Application.EnableEvents = True
  Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Given that this is a XLS file with macros (*.xlsm), and that these are considered to be malicious by most AV software these days, I could very well imagine that the actual Excel file's content has been replace by something else, though keeping the original filename. Hence the "corrupted" message by Excel. Save the file to disk and open it with a text editor, e.g. Notepad and see what's in there.

Comment: In other words (as @Hel O'Ween stated), if the active workbook is `.xls`, or `.xlsx` type and you try saving it with `.xlsm` extension, it is not enough to create a macro enabled workbook... Just curious: Why do you try this way? What do you want accomplishing?

Comment: @HelO'Ween Thank you for the response - I've opened the file in notepad as suggested and the file is unreadable. The contents look like 

'Œè·œŽHÞð<Ñæv¢ÿ¯Å‰J„Z_æ9u\ZßtÝ¢eÇ¯;óˆß†ƒÈP¬;™ƒ‹¨   ÿÿ PK  ' 

I would assume this means the file is corrupted?

Comment: Try opening the active workbook in Notepad and it will look similarly...

Comment: @FaneDuru So if the original workbook is 'xlsm' format, should the macro be saving the temp file as the same format?

Comment: Not exactly... You can correctly SaveAsCopy the active workbook using **its own extension**. Not some extension which is  not suitable with the way the workbook has initially been created/built. Anyhow, not having any code inside, it looks absurd to try saving it as macro enabled type. You can do it, using SaveAs, but using a specific setting to make it macro enabled. And the remained document (in the memory and in Excel session) will keep the new name/extension.

Comment: BTW, what is the file's original file format? The old *.xls or the new *.xslx? If the fomer, you can't simply rename it and expect it to work. You need to do a proper conversion into the new Office format first.

Comment: @HelO'Ween The files original format is `.xlsm` so would i still need to do a conversion to the new office format?

Comment: If you are talking about the **active workbook** in your code, the answer is NO, no needed to make any conversion (because nothing is to be converted). But, if will not fail on opening, in such a case...

Comment: @FaneDuru The 'Report' tab does have shapes with macros assigned however the user wont be running these. Can my above code be adapted to resolve this? If so, any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'm afraid I cannot get you... If your code never tries saving a .xlsx workbook in a .xlsm type, you should not have the problem you try clarifying. I do not know what "The 'Report' tab" does mean. I was asking for clarifications only in terms of **active workbook** used by the active code. Now, I do not understand what kind of help do you need.

Comment: @FaneDuru My apologies, let me try this again. The active workbook has multiple sheets, one of which is labelled 'Report'(Sheet 5). The active workbook's file type is `.xlsm`. When running the macro that's on 'Report'(Sheet 5) an email is populated with 'Report'(Sheet 5) attached. I get the errors mentioned above when attempting to open the attachment.

Comment: I cannot see any part of your code trying to save only a sheet. Now, if the macro "that's on 'Report'(Sheet 5)" does not run on the `SourceWB`, I am afraid that I cannot understand your code and I cannot be of any hel...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The original file and the attachment don't have the same format (the problem has nothing to do with sending the file per mail).

The original file is a file containing Macros, file type is (most likely) `xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled` (52), extension is `xlsm`. You copy one of the sheets (sheet5) into a *new* workbook. What Excel does when you use the `copy` method is to create a workbook in the default file format (you can set this in the Excel Options under "Save"). In most cases this is format `xlOpenXMLWorkbook` (51), that is a macro-free workbook, extension `xlsx`.

What you now do is you save this workbook using the `SaveCopyAs` method. You provide a filename with an extension `xlsm`, **but this doesn't change the file format**. So you still have a file that is a macro-free workbook, but with the extension of a macro-enabled workbook. So extension and file format doesn't fit, and therefore you will get the error message that you (or whoever receives the mail) see.

You can easily proof this by removing the `kill` command, go to your temp folder and try to open the file - you will get the very same error message. Now rename the file to `.xlsx` and voilà, you can open the file.

There are some issues with your code. I guess you should refactor the code and split it to at least 2 routines: One saving the sheet as workbook and one that sends the mail. With that, you can test your functionality much easier because saving and sending are two separate tasks.

You don't need to `select` a sheet when you want to copy it (you hardly ever need to select or activate anything at all), and you shouldn't access the sheet via the `Window`-property. Simply use `ActiveWorkbook.sheets(5).Copy`.

After copying the sheet, you created a new workbook - you just need to save it. Don't use `SaveCopyAs` for that, use `SaveAs`. There, you can specify a filetype, and Excel will happily save the file in the format you want (and convert if necessary).
If you insist, you could save the copy as Macro-enabled, but as you send the file via mail, macro-free is usually the better option. Just be aware that filetype and extension fit. Or omit the extension at all, it that case Excel will add it for you automatically.

I refactored your code, have a look

```
Sub EmailSelectedSheets()
    'Optimize Code
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False

    Dim tmpFileName As String
    tmpFileName = SaveSheetAsTempFile(ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)) ' Or whatever you want to save...
    
    SendMail tmpFileName

    Kill tmpFileName
    
ExitSub:
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub

Function SaveSheetAsTempFile(ws As Worksheet) As String
    Dim DestinWB As Workbook
    ws.Copy
    Set DestinWB = ActiveWorkbook
    
    ExternalLinks = DestinWB.LinkSources(Type:=xlLinkTypeExcelLinks)
    'Loop Through each External Link in ActiveWorkbook and Break it
    On Error Resume Next
        Dim x As Long
        For x = 1 To UBound(ExternalLinks)
            DestinWB.BreakLink Name:=ExternalLinks(x), Type:=xlLinkTypeExcelLinks
        Next x
    On Error GoTo 0
        
    Dim tmpFileName As String
    tmpFileName = Left(ws.Parent.Name, InStrRev(ws.Parent.Name, ".") - 1)
    tmpFileName = Environ$("temp") & "\" & tmpFileName & ".xlsx"
    
    DestinWB.SaveAs tmpFileName, xlOpenXMLWorkbook
    SaveSheetAsTempFile = tmpFileName

End Function

Sub SendMail(attachmentName As String)
    ' do your email sending stuff here...
    .Attachments.Add attachmentName 
End Sub
```